# How to fix: site getting redirected to another domain?

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, http-status-code-301, lets-encrypt

**Problem:**

My web hosting provider (apache) supports having multiple domains under one account, theese domains cointain wordpress installations and are managed via ftp client in a path:

```
www/domains/domain1.tld
www/domains/domain2.tld
```

When I open https://domain2.tld everything works as intended.

[image]

Anyways.. if I dont specify the 'https://' then it gets redirected to https://domain1.tld

[image]

**What I have:**

in **www/domains** I have this **.htaccess** file

```
RewriteEngine On
# domains
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^domains/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/domains/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.*)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/domains/%2 -d
RewriteRule (.*) domains/%2/$1 [DPI]

# subdomains
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^subdom/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdom/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.*)\.([^\.]*)\.([^\.]*)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/subdom/%2 -d
RewriteRule (.*) subdom/%2/$1 [DPI]

# domains proper redirection when / is missing
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^domains/[^/]+/(.+[^/])$ /$1/ [R]

# subdomains proper redirection when / is missing
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^subdom/[^/]+/(.+[^/])$ /$1/ [R]
```

Then in each WP installation i have the wordpress **.htacces** file

```
# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301]  
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
# END WordPress
```

- I did check database and wp-config, none of them contains links to
  https://domain1.ltd
- Both domains use Lets Encrypt certificate
- I did search domain2.ltd localy with notepad++ for domain1.ltd occurences, found none, disabling all plugins didnt help either

Forcing https redirection didnt work either with:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain2\.tld [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.domain2.tld/$1 [R=301,QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.domain2.tld/$1 [R=301,L]
```

To be honest i ran out of ideas what to do next. Anyone knows how to trubleshoot this? My guess is there is something wrong with the **www/domains** .htaccess file, or the web host.

Thank you guys!

Comment: Do you have access to the apache config? Specifically the virtual host files?

Comment: sadly i don't.. only the .htaccess

Comment: Disable the WP .htaccess files completely, request a static `foo.txt` file you put into the base folder of each WP installation - same problem then? Then I’d ask the hoster to fix it, it would appear to be a mistake with their part of the setup already.

Comment: @04FS that just returns 403 Forbidden error

Comment: What, with _no_ .htaccess in play, and just requesting a physically existing file? (Did you make sure that file is readable by the web server?)

Comment: @04FS my bad, easy to forget.. yeah, if i request foo.txt with wp .htaccess disabled i get redirected too.. interesting thing tho is I dont need the .htaccess in the domain2 (which i get redirected from to domain1), while i need the .htaccess in domain1, else the 403 on both

Answer (score 1):

In the end it was a wrong placement of the main htaccess file, which should be in www/ dricetory, not in www/domains

Anyways thank you for your time guys! :)